# node.js Web Service The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request

Tags: node.js

I use node.js for back-end to provide service for mobile.
I was test it and run it correctly on my local PC but when I upload my project to live server and test my service with postman tool it show message as below.
Sometimes it response correctly and sometime show this error message.
Anybody know the solution to fix it?

[image: Error message when request data from server]

Comment: `502 Bad Gateway` often means there's something wrong with your server's reverse proxy - do you route requests to your Node application via Apache/Nginx or something along those lines?

Comment: Sorry I ready don't know how to know what is my route requests?

Answer (score 0):

> > Add required file in app.js whatever name of your file.
> >     var passport = require('passport'); var  LocalStrategy =
> >     require('passport-local').Strategy;
>
> Now add some another code in app.js file for checking log in the user.
>
> router.post('/login',
>   passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/users/login',
>   failureFlash: 'Messsage',title: 'Login'}),   function(req,res,next) { 
>   req.flash('success', 'success message');    res.redirect('/'); });
>
> passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {   done(null, user.id);
>   });
>
> passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {   User.getUserById(id,
>   function(err, user) {
>       done(err, user);   }); });
>
> passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
>   User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
>       if(err) throw err;
>       if(!user){
>         return done(null, false, {message: 'message'});
>       }
>
> ```
> User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
>   if(err) return done(err);
>   if(isMatch){
>     return done(null, user);
>   } else {
>     return done(null, false, {message:'Invalid Password'});
>   }
> });   }); }));
> ```

May be this will halp you